# Obtener valor child firebase android

Tags: android, json, firebase

Me gustaria mantener un id a través del que guardar y buscar las diferentes actividades que estoy almacenando.

La linea de código que utilizo para guardarlo es la siguiente:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("actividades").child(idChild).setValue(actividad);
```

Lo que trato de obtener es el último valor de `idChild` que se guardó, para así asignarle a la nueva actividad el `idChild` incrementando. El valor que trato de obtener en la imagen sería el "1".

La base de datos se mostraría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Sino, también me sirve recorrer todo lo correspondiente a actividades, poner un contador y estaría.

¿Alguna idea de como recorrer todos?

Gracias

Comment: El idChild es el mismo que el campo **id** que está bajo hora?

Comment: Si, es el mismo campo, lo único que el de abajo es un int, y para el de arriba lo convierto a String

Comment: Y qué valor obtienes o qué error te marca en esa línea?

Comment: No me marca ningún error, lo que quiero hacer es obtener el último valor que esté debajo de actividades

Comment: Estoy probando con esto, pero el resultado que obtendo es "actividades" FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("actividades").getKey();

Comment: Si eliminas esta parte .setValue(actividad), te devuelve lo mismo?

Comment: Eso lo hago para guardar la actividad. También me valdría contar el numero de actividades con un for y sabría cuantas hay y por tanto la ultima. ¿Alguna idea de como hacer ese bucle? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a ir almacenando mas valores que pueden ser `1,2,3,4,5` y queres acceder al ultimo elemento puesto en la base de datos podes usar `limitToLast(1)`

Documentacion: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419#section-queries

Uso

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("actividades").orderBykey().limitToLast(1).addSingleValueForEvent...
```

De esta forma te aseguras ordenar por las keys que guardas y limitas la busqueda al ultimo elemento agregado

### Tip

No deberias usar valores incrementales para los nodos de tus datos en la base de datos , ya que no es una buena practica, lo que deberias usar seria un .push() que genera un valor aleatorio alphanumerico con un timestamp en el momento que lo creas, de esta forma nunca van a ser unicos los valores, por ejemplo podrias generar claves aleatorias de la siguiente manera

Desde la [documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?hl=es-419)

> Si se proporciona una ruta de acceso de clave única como
>   alanisawesome, solo se actualizan los datos en el primer nivel
>   secundario y cualquier dato que se pase más allá del primer nivel
>   secundario se tratará como una operación set. El comportamiento en
>   varias rutas de acceso permite usar rutas de acceso más largas (como
>   alanisawesome/nickname) sin sobrescribir datos. Es por ello que el
>   primer ejemplo se diferencia del segundo.

Ejemplo

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("actividades").push().setValue(actividad);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. He usado el segundo tip que me ha puesto, pero a la hora de asignar un id (1,2,3,4...) al campo del objeto actividad como podría ir incrementando dicho valor según se van guardando objetos?